# Is it possible to use a hash type secondary index in scylladb?

Tags: cassandra, cql, scylla

Table for explanation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id    INT,
    uniuque_string      VARCHAR,
    another_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, uniuque_string))
);
```

Sometimes it is necessary to make such requests:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WHERE another_id = 12;
```

but `another_id` is not a primary key.

How can I create a hash index (for example, like in mysql) by this column?

Answer (score 0):

Scylla and Cassandra have two features that fit your needs **secondary index** and **materialized view**:

You enable a **secondary index** on `another_id` with the command:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test (another_id);
```

And now your query `SELECT * FROM test WHERE another_id = 12;` will work normally. You should be aware that if this `SELECT` returns a huge number of results (a so-called *low-cardinality* index) this select is inefficient - it retrieves just the keys from the index, and to show everything (the `SELECT *`) Scylla needs to go back to the table and fetch its rows one by one, a fairly inefficient process.

The second alternative is a **materialized** view with `another_id` as a partition key, as in the command:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_by_another_id AS
    SELECT * FROM test
    WHERE another_id IS NOT NULL AND uniuque_string IS NOT NULL and id IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (another_id, id, uniuque_string);
```

This *materialized view* will contain a copy of all the data (not just keys) from `test`, and can be searched by another key. For example: `SELECT * FROM test_by_another_id WHERE another_id = 12;` (note we had to replace `test` by the view`test_by_another_id`.

The materialized-view solution will make long selects much more efficient than the secondary-index solution, but it requires more storage (all the data is stored twice), so both solutions should be considered depending on your use case.

Comment: Table is too huge for materialized view.

Comment: What storage structure will the secondary index have?

Comment: What makes a table "too huge for a materialized view"? At worst - if you copy all columns to the view, it will double the table size. Whether or not this is worth it depends on your access pattern.
A secondary index is implemented differently in Scylla and Cassandra (and Cassandra has several different implementations). But conceptually, it is a materialized view of just the indexed column and the keys, and nothing else - if you want to read additional columns while scanning the index, the result will be reads from the base table.